# Hypothesis Testing for small sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, small-sample

I am a somewhat dubious about how to apply some hypothesis testing for this case or maybe it is not applicable at all.

In an undergraduate Algebra course, the Faculty has been using a book from author A for almost 3 years in a row. The mathematics department has chosen the last year a new book from author B. Each year 40 students enrolled in the course approximately and the non-pass rate is around 20%. Last year only 15 students passed the course and the professor believes that the new book has caused that drop in the student's marks.

How to perform a hypothesis test for the above case?

```
Ho:P=0.2
Ha:P>0.20
```

sample proportion `p'=25/40=0.625`

test statistic:

```
z=(0.625-0.2)/sqrt(0.2(1-0.2)/40)=0.425/0.0632455=6.71984
```

For what I have been reading it says that I should calculate the p-value based on the z value obtained. I have used this online calculator: http://graphpad.com/quickcalcs/pValue2/

Then answer I got is that:

```
Z=6.71984   
   The two-tailed P value is less than 0.0001
   By conventional criteria, this difference is considered to be extremely statistically significant.
```

Does it mean that I can reject the null hypothesis so that indeed the new book is the responsible for a drop in the students' marks?

PD. I do not have any statistics background about hypothesis testing and I am not pretty sure if what I have done is right.

Comment: Please add the self-study tag to this post since it appears to be homework.

Comment: It would only mean significantly more students have failed this time but it does not necessarily mean that it is due to change in the book. However, one could deduce that if all other factors have remained the same.